# Getting Error while adding pubcenter ads in Metro App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have followed these steps

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn284011(v=msads.10).aspx

At step 10 when i press ok i get a message that says

> An Error Occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you cannot create new application and adunit in PubCenter for now. PubCenter has been integrated into Windows Dev Center.

Note: You will no longer be able to create ad units or new app promotion campaigns in pubCenter. For information on how to create ad units in Dev Center, see Monetize with ads. For information on how to create app promotion campaigns in Dev Center, see Create an ad campaign for your app.
Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186437.aspx for details

Answer (score 0):

I think the process evolved and you should follow this guide : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt313186(v=msads.30).aspx